# Can someone explain me why variable $x is printing 1?

Tags: php

I'm just checking my following php code. it's should be show 0 but why it's showing me 1 ? Can you explain it ?

```
<?php
$x = (bool) " " * (int) (string) 12E-1;
echo $x;
?>

output: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a = (bool) " ";//true
$b = (string) 12E-1;//"1.2"
$c = (int) $b;//1
$x = $a * $c;//true * 1, typecasting to int
var_dump($a);
var_dump($b);
var_dump($c);
var_dump($x);
//prints bool(true) string(3) "1.2" int(1) int(1)
```

Comment: thanks for your Answer. I understand it. I'm beginner of php.

Comment: One more thing. `" "` is it empty string ? If not why ?

Comment: " " is not empty string, a white space may look empty to human eyes but not for a computer...Try yourself `$a = "";var_dump(empty($a));` and then `$a = " ";var_dump(empty($a));`